# Finding a way to avoid IP spoofing on application authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, spoofing

I've developed C# application, which uses authorization via TCP. It connects to server application (located on amazon VPS), sends authorization string and gets response. The TCP information exchange flow is encrypted via TLS1.2 and also additionally with Rijndael symmetric encryption. Also inside the client application there is a check for SSLStream on RemoteCertificateValidationCallback where thumbprint of the ssl certificate obtained from serer is compared with the hardcoded one. The client applcation is obfuscated with .NetReactor, also with option to produce native .exe, and this exe additionally is compressed with Themida. But the hacker has somehow cracked the protocol and created his own fake authorization server and selling the illegal copy of program to his "clients". Each time I change the encryption secret key, he immediately goes out with new update, so it is infinite struggle. He doesn't need to crack the client .exe, he just updates the server on his side.  I know he uses Windows standart postproxy to redirect the traffic, I've made addtional checks inside the client exe for existance of windows postproxy records in registry, but it didn't do any effect.

So my question is: is there any way in C# to check if application connects to the "correct" server and not the "fake" one? I'm using standard TcpClient class for authorization, but can migrate to something else if it can help.

Comment: Your environment is likely compromised severely. "*I'm using standard TcpClient class for authorization*" this is also very suspect. Don't roll your own security. Use industry standard identity techniques.

Comment: Sounds like certificate-pinning (public key pinning) might help?

Comment: @00110001  "Your environment is likely compromised severely" - yes I feel like that, but no mailware is found on my developer PC (tried with different scanners), also I don't see any strange activity. VPS with server has logon IP restrictions and also there is no records found in logs with suspicious entries. We use our own licensing system for easier management if the client migrates from one PC to another, so we need some web service for authorization, the common approach of making "lic" file is not working for us

Comment: @AndreasHassing thanks for the idea. Do you know if that works with standard C# classes?

Comment: I think you need to go after whoever signed his code, as it's clearly fraudulent. Once his code-signing cert is revoked then he is going to have his customers complaining

Answer (score 0):

As @00110001 mentions, you probably have more issues than this, but maybe [public key pinning can help you](https://www.basdecort.com/protecting-your-users-with-certificate-pinning/).

Assuming that your binary is signed (i.e. cannot easily be altered after downloading directly from your website, without incurring warnings during start):

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
{
    if (sender is HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest
        && httpWebRequest.RequestUri.Host.Contains("<your pinned domain>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return _allowedPublicKeys.Contains(certificate?.GetPublicKeyString());
    }
    else if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

But if the "hacker" is re-publishing your binaries with their changes, which it seems like the person does as they point to another authorization server, you're out of luck.

---

Edit: If you're using `HttpClient` and need only to pin *some* outbound requests, you can do something like:

```cs
internal HttpClient GetSecureHttpClient()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        if (httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.Host.Contains("<your pinned domain>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return _allowedPublicKeys.Contains(certificate?.GetPublicKeyString());
        }
        else if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    return client;
}

// use:
var _ = await GetSecureHttpClient().GetAsync("https://google.com");
```

See dotnetfiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q1ggDS

Comment: To correct: not completely out of luck, there are even more obfuscation and obstacles you can place in the way of your attacker, but given enough time and effort they can _always_ be broken; so who is more patient? You or the attacker? :-)

Comment: The problem is - he (or they) don't change the binaries (they are signed), they leave it as is but with some windows techincs (or 3rd party apps)  make the redirection of traffic from "real" server to "fake". As I have no patience to struggle and bring more obstacles (you are completely right) I thought may be is there a way to avoid applicaiton to be redirected to "fake" server, so make some checks in the code, as the source exe remains unchanged.

Comment: The idea of key pinning is cool, but I can't make global list for using  ServicePointManager, as the applicaiton allows user to make connection to the different hosts which can have their own certificates, and I don't know them in advance.

Comment: @IlyaT edited my answer to solve for this issue and also add an alternative that isolates the change to a single `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working with the TCPClient, and use SslStream class for TLS connection. It do has RemoteCertificateValidationCallback function, and I tried to use it in the way you are sugegsting, but he avoids this check somehow(